# Create a global variable that can be used in my console

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm new to this forum. Despite my extensive research on your website and internet, I do not find what I am looking for.
I want to create a global variable with TypeScript and under Angular 4, so I can use this variable on my console afterwards.

Let me explain :
I created a 'MyGlobal' interface, where I created my global variable 'message_chat':

```
import {ChatService} from "./chat-service/chat.service";

export interface MyGlobal {
   message_chat: ChatService;
}
```

I want to be able to initialize this variable in my 'ChatService' service. I want this variable to take the value of 'this':

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { MessageService } from '../message/message.service';
import { MyGlobal } from '../my-global';

@Injectable()
export class ChatService implements MyGlobal {
  message_chat: ChatService;
    constructor(public threadService: ThreadService,
                public messageService: MessageService) {
     this.message_chat = this;
    } 
}

export const chatServiceInjectables: Array<any> = [
 ChatService
];
```

When I try to use this variable in my console, I have this error:

```
message_chat.openThread()

    VM140:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: message_chat is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Thank you for your help :)

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

UPDATE :

This is my ChatService :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { MyGlobal } from '../my-global';

@Injectable()
export class ChatService implements MyGlobal {

etiam_chat: ChatService;

constructor(public threadService: ThreadService,
      public messageService: MessageService) {
this.etiam_chat = this;
}


addNewMessage(objMessage: any) : void {
 this.threadService.getThreadFromSubscription(objMessage.id)
.subscribe ((thread: Thread) => {
  objMessage.thread = thread;
});

if (objMessage.thread != null) {
const newMessage = new Message(objMessage);
this.addMessage(newMessage);
}
else {
const newThread: Thread = new Thread(objMessage.id, 
objMessage.name);
objMessage.thread = newThread;
const newMessage = new Message(objMessage);
this.addMessage(newMessage);
  } 
 }
}
```

Should I do this to use my addNewMessage function in my console ?

```
@Injectable()
export class ChatService implements MyGlobal {

etiam_chat: ChatService;

constructor(public threadService: ThreadService,
      public messageService: MessageService) {
this.etiam_chat = this;
this.addNewMessage(objMessage: any) : void => {
this.threadService.getThreadFromSubscription(objMessage.id)
.subscribe ((thread: Thread) => {
  objMessage.thread = thread;
});

 if (objMessage.thread != null) {
  const newMessage = new Message(objMessage);
  this.addMessage(newMessage);
  }
  else {
  const newThread: Thread = new Thread(objMessage.id, 
  objMessage.name);
  objMessage.thread = newThread;
  const newMessage = new Message(objMessage);
   this.addMessage(newMessage);
    }
   };
  }
```

Comment: Add the chat service in the appmodule providers and inject into the contructor.

Comment: I've already added ChatService to 'app.module.ts'.
And it does not change anything if I add it in the constructor ..

Comment: Create a empty constructor and use new ChatService();

Comment: I'm not sure I understand ..
Like this in my 'ChatService' : 
constructor(public chatService: ChatService) {
    new ChatService();
  }

Comment: Like this constructor(){} and new ChatService

Comment: Sorry but it does not work .

Comment: What makes the MyGlobal interface special so you think its properties become global variables?

Comment: I do not know, I had seen an example like that. He said that to define a global variable, it had to be passed in an interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application source files are put together using some tool like Webpack and trans-compiled from TypeScript to JavaScript of some version. Neither your classes nor their properties become global variables. Global variables are the ones bound to the `window` object. So if you want to create one, you must do something like

```
window.messageChat = something;
```

But it's probably not a good idea if you want it for anything else than debugging purposes.

Comment: OK, thanks. Indeed this is not for debugging.
I want to create this variable to be able to write my functions in the console so that they execute.

Comment: Or is it possible to write a function in the console and execute it ?

Comment: Do you mean to define a function in a console and run it? Yes, it's possible, just write `function hello() { console.log('Hello'); return 'World'; }` and then `hello()`.

Comment: No I mean define my function in my service, then call it and run it in my console.

Comment: Ah, yes, that works. You can consider organizing your function in a single object, so you call them like `myApp.hello()` or `myApp.logout()`. This way, you can list all your API using `console.log(myApp)` and your functions will not pollute the global name space.

Comment: What is 'myApp' ? Is it my selector of my component ?

Comment: `myApp` is the only window-level variable that you introduce. Something like `window['myApp'] = { hello: () => { ... }, logout: () => { ... } }` instead of `window['hello'] = ...` and `window['logout'] = ...`.

Comment: Yes but where I can find the variable 'myApp' ?

Comment: You define it as a new variable (`window['myApp'] = ...`) that will contain all the functions you want to have available in a console.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to help me .. Do you mean like that ?

`code public window['MyApp']: void = {
    addNewMessage(objMessage: any) : void {
      this.threadService.getThreadFromSubscription(objMessage.id)
        .subscribe ((thread: Thread) => {
          objMessage.thread = thread;
        });

      if (objMessage.thread != null) {
        const newMessage = new Message(objMessage);
        this.addMessage(newMessage);
      }
      else {
        const newThread: Thread = new Thread(objMessage.id, objMessage.name);
      }
    }
  };`

Comment: `window` is a global variable available in a browser. So there is no need to declare it. Just add your functions into it in a constructor of your service the way I wrote in my message above.